# Query XML column in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008

I have following XML in table `ALL_MRN` column `PID3`:

```
<Repetitions>
 <Repetition>
  <Field>10228^^^L8 MRN^MRN</Field>
  <Component_1>10228</Component_1>
  <Component_2>L8 MRN</Component_2>
  <Component_3>MRN</Component_3>
 </Repetition>
 <Repetition>
  <Field>00283^^^CMRN^CMRN</Field>
  <Component_1>00283</Component_1>
  <Component_2>CMRN</Component_2>
  <Component_3>CMRN</Component_3>
 </Repetition>
 <Repetition>
  <Field>00294^^^L7 MRN^MRN</Field>
  <Component_1>00283</Component_1>
  <Component_2>L7 MRN</Component_2>
  <Component_3>MRN</Component_3>
 </Repetition>
</Repetitions>
```

I am trying to find the `CMRN` value in a `Component_3` tag and if found then concatenate the values from `Component_1` and `Component_3` to form a string.

Is it possible without using cursors or loops? What is the best way to get this concatenated string?

Comment: You have closing tag `</Component_5>` for opening tag `<Component_3>` and 4 for 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
SELECT
    C1_and_C3 = XRep.value('(Component_1)[1]', 'varchar(50)') + XRep.value('(Component_3)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
FROM 
    dbo.ALL_MRN
CROSS APPLY 
    PID3.nodes('/Repetitions/Repetition') AS XTbl(XRep)
WHERE
    XRep.value('(Component_3)[1]', 'varchar(50)') = 'CMRN'
```

SQL Server 2005 and newer have pretty great XQuery support - there's really no need for cursors!

BTW: your XML is invalid - you cannot have a leading `<Component_3>` tag and close that with a `</Component_5>` (same goes for `<Component_2>....</Component_4>` )

Answer (score 2):

Another option, which uses the XQuery language and [exist](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189869.aspx) method.
If the exist method return a 1(True), it indicates that Component_3 tag includes the CMRN value

```
DECLARE @xml xml =
'<Repetitions>
 <Repetition>
  <Field>10228^^^L8 MRN^MRN</Field>
  <Component_1>10228</Component_1>
  <Component_2>L8 MRN</Component_2>
  <Component_3>MRN</Component_3>
 </Repetition>
<Repetition>
 <Field>00283^^^CMRN^CMRN</Field>
 <Component_1>00283</Component_1>
 <Component_2>CMRN</Component_2>
 <Component_3>CMRN</Component_3>
</Repetition>
<Repetition>
 <Field>00294^^^L7 MRN^MRN</Field>
 <Component_1>00283</Component_1>
 <Component_2>L7 MRN</Component_2>
 <Component_3>MRN</Component_3>
 </Repetition>
</Repetitions>'

DECLARE @Component_3 varchar(50) = 'CMRN'
SELECT xmlCol.value('Component_1[1]', 'varchar(50)') + xmlCol.value('Component_3[1]', 'varchar(50)') 
FROM @xml.nodes('//Repetitions/Repetition') xmlTab(xmlCol)
WHERE xmlCol.exist('Component_3[text() = sql:variable("@Component_3")]') = 1
```

See demo on [`SQLFiddle`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/18842)

Answer (score 1):

It worked. PID3 was varchar type so I had to cast to XML. Here is the updated version.

```
SELECT
  C1_and_C3 = XRep.value('(Component_1)[1]', 'varchar(50)') + XRep.value('(Component_3)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
FROM 
  dbo.ALL_MRN
CROSS APPLY 
  (select cast(PID3 as XML) ) as t1(x)
CROSS APPLY 
  x.nodes('/Repetitions/Repetition') AS XTbl(XRep)
WHERE
  XRep.value('(Component_3)[1]', 'varchar(50)') = 'CMRN'
```